# Memory conflict between application and Windows Aero theme

Tags: .net, windows, memory, themes

We have a customer running our VB.Net application on a 32-bit 4 GB Windows 7 computer using the Windows Aero theme. During certain operations, they receive a System Access Violation Exception. In looking at the details, it appears that our application is conflicting with xtheme.dll. Having the customer disable their Windows Aero theme resolves the issue.

My question is this: This application runs on thousands of computers, yet this is the first report of something like this. Is there something on the customer's computer we should be looking at or having them change, or is it more likely that our application is misbehaving in some way? The application is developed entirely within the vb.net framework so it should be running as managed code.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like this is a system-specific error.  I would check that the theme isn't a 3rd party theme installed with some "toolbar" (ie malware).

Comment: Cosmic rays.  If your software is adequately tested and running on thousands of other boxes successfully, you are likely wasting your time investigating an isolated repro of this bug. Most likely it's exactly what U1199880 said above.